# Parsing a CSV file into another file, without CSV module, addressing indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Is there a way to do it better in Python 3.8? I'm opening `INPUTFILE` with 4 `,` delimited values. I need to select the first and third columns and write them into `OUTPUTFILE` file.

```py
with open('INPUTFILE', 'r') as input_file, open('OUTPUTFILE', 'w') as sorted_output: 
    for lines in INPUTFILE:
        splitted_list = lines.split(',')
        sorted_output.write(splitted_list[0]) 
        sorted_output.write(',')       
        sorted_output.write(splitted_list[3]) 
        sorted_output.write('\n')
```

It works; but I can't figure out how to remove the last `\n` at the end (last line).

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `csv`module? it makes things much easier

Comment: the third element is `splitted_list[2]` and not `3`

Comment: Why no CSV, because I am a pervert. Joke. I am learning and trying to get by without extra libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps:

```
with open('friends.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('OUTPUTFILE', 'w') as sorted_output: 
    data = input_file.readlines()
    d = ["{0},{1}".format(i.strip().split(",")[0], i.strip().split(",")[3]) for i in data]
    sorted_output.write("\n".join(d))
```

Here is my input/output file:

```
John,555-234-9876,May 5,123
Mary,556-987-2367,December 12,123
Albert,555-987-6765,June 12,123
Leo,555-789-9865,February 25,123
Ruth,555-786-1238,October 2,123
Fred,556-235-4536,June 17,123%  

John,123
Mary,123
Albert,123
Leo,123
Ruth,123
Fred,123
```

Comment: Thanks, good alternative, just harder to read for me at least. I assume it might be easy for more experienced with the syntax.

Comment: So, what is happening here is, we read all data from input files, use comprehension to select only 0th and 3rd element from every line, and instead of writing "\n" everytime in the output file, I am joining out data using "join", that ensures, we dont end up with additional "\n" in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
with open("INPUTFILE", 'r') as input_file, open("OUTPUTFILE", 'w') as sorted_output:
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        tmp = line.split(",")
        output = ",".join([tmp[0], tmp[2]])
        sorted_output.write(output + '\n')
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, does same thing, but it also adds Empty String to the very bottom of the file. How could I effectively remove it from the very bottom?

Comment: Nice catch. Hmm...I'd probably replace that last line with another `.join()` statement.  So, `sorted_output.write("\n".join(output))`.  Appending a newline character like we have it will definitely add some space at the bottom, while `.join()` shouldn't do that.